# why does curl sometimes return a single line JSON response?

Tags: macos, curl, github-api, user-agent

I'm trying to get an nVidia GPU working on my MacPro, using the https://github.com/mayankk2308/purge-wrangler script, and I've run into a problem.

The installation instructions fail on my MacPro, but they succeed on my MacBookPro.  Both are running the same OSX version (Mojave 10.14.2), and the same version of curl (curl 7.63.0).

Here are the instructions ...

```sh
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mayankk2308/purge-wrangler/master/resources/webdrv-release.sh | bash
```

This returns and executes the following script ...

```sh
curl -s "https://api.github.com/repos/mayankk2308/purge-wrangler/releases/latest" | grep '"browser_download_url":' | sed -E 's/.*"([^"]+)".*/\1/' | xargs curl -L -s -0 > purge-wrangler.sh && chmod +x purge-wrangler.sh && ./purge-wrangler.sh && rm purge-wrangler.sh
```

The problem is that curl is returning a single-line response on my MacPro and a multi-line response everywhere else.  I'm trying to understand what is different on my machines to cause such radically different behavior.

This must be a server side switch, but I'm not sure what it is.

NOTE:  the sed(1) line is easily updated to support both single/multi line responses, but I'd like to get to the bottom of what's different on my two machines.

Anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

The problem turns out to be the following two lines in my ~/.curlrc ...

```
# Disguise as IE 9 on Windows 7.
user-agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)"
```

Specifying this user agent affects how https://api.github.com returns it's JSON responses (single or multi-line).

I honestly have no idea why this line was in my ~/.curlrc file, but I suspect others must have hit this same problem and just worked around it.